# ElasticSearch Score Function Depending on Neighbor Documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ElasticSearch index with 2 mappings (types).
In the app I need to display a paginated feed containing items of both types.
Currently the items are sorted just by creation date, but I also want to have control on how the items alternate with each other on the page.
For example, I want to set a rule for sequence "3 items of type A, 1 item of type B, and so on".
I need it to make sure items of both types are displayed on each page and equally distributed across the pages.

But as far as I see it's not possible to access another documents in custom score function script.

Of course it's easy to implement directly in the app logic, but it's not clear how to implement pagination using this way.

Any ideas on how to achieve that?

Comment: What kind of IDs do you have for these documents?

Comment: Regular integers (which represent mysql autoincrement IDs).

Comment: If your results are sorted by creation date, how does this play with `3 items of type A, 1 item of type B, and so on`? Sorting on date will not make sense anymore.

Comment: No :-). Like that you will have all docs of type 1 be before those of type 2. Hehe, you deleted your comment :-)

Comment: Sorting on date will be only the first sort. The documents will be resorted based on the type then.

Comment: The issue is exactly in that I can't describe that in terms of SQL or ElasticSearch functions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this.

One approach (that doesn't work) is to keep a global variable in a script and to increment that once every document is being returned/processed. And then to take this number, divide it by 3 and get the modulo number. Based on this number, to sort the docs. **But** "global" variables are not possible in sripts.

The only two approaches that I can think of is to use a script to generate a random number and based on that to sort. In this way, you get some chances to have a "mixed list of types.

Or, if you want the smallest deterministic way of sorting the docs, still in a script take the ID of the document (you said is a number) modulo 3 it and use the value to sort.

For the random approach:

```
  "sort": [
    {
      "date": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    {
      "_script": {
        "script": "Math.random()",
        "type": "number",
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
```